# An exercise asks me to change the body of the loop. What does it mean?

Tags: c++

I am fairly new to C++ still, as well as programming and the terms used. I'm learning off of "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++" (as was gifted to me) and I ran into a problem on a Drill at the end of chapter four. The drill is split into twelve exercises, where the first five are as follows:

> 1. Write a program that consists of a while-loop that (each time around the loop) reads in two ints and then prints them. Exit the
>      program when a terminating '|' is entered.
> 2. Change the program to write out the smaller value is: followed by the smaller of the numbers and the larger value is: followed by the
>      larger value.
> 3. Augment the program so that it writes the line the numbers are equal (only) if they are equal.
> 4. Change the program so that it uses doubles instead of ints.
> 5. Change the program so that it writes out the numbers are almost equal after writing out which is the larger and the smaller if the two
>      numbers differ by less than 1.0/100.

I've dealt with those exercises, but now I don't quite get what to do in the next exercise:

> 6. Now change the body of the loop so that it reads just one double each time around. Define two variables to keep track of which is the smallest and which is the largest value you have
>      seen so far. Each time through the loop write out the value entered. If it’s the smallest so far, write the smallest so far after the number. If it is the largest so far, write the largest so far after the number.

I don't get it. What should I do with the loop? **What's exercise 6 actually about?**

---

My code I have made up so far from step five is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
//Name 
int main()
{
char terminate = ' ';
double one = 0.0;
double two = 0.0;
int one_i = one;
int two_i = two;
while (terminate != '|')
{
    std::cout << "Input two numbers, follow each one by enter: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> one;
    std::cin >> two;
    if (one == two)
    {
        std::cout << "The two numbers are equal to each other." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "To terminate this program, type \"|\" into the system followed by pressing enter twice." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> terminate;
        if (terminate == '|')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Here is the larger value: ";
    if (one > two)
    {
        std::cout << one << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if (two > one)
        {
            std::cout << two << std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Here is the smaller value: ";
    if (one < two)
    {
        std::cout << one << std::endl;
        if (one_i == two_i || two_i == one_i)
        {
            std::wcout << "The numbers are almost equal." << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (two < one)
        {
            std::cout << two << std::endl;
            if (one_i == two_i || two_i == one_i)
            {
                std::wcout << "The numbers are almost equal." << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "To terminate this program, type \"|\" into the system followed by pressing enter twice." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> terminate;
}
}
```

I attempted to figure out the problem if this code helps any of you see as to what degree I'm confused on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
//Name
int main()
{
char terminate = ' ';
std::vector<double>num_size;

while (terminate != '|')
{
    std::cout << "Type in a number: " << std::endl;
    for (double num; std::cin >> num;)
    {
        num_size.push_back(num);
        std::sort(num_size.begin(), num_size.end());

    }
    std::cout << "To terminate this program, type \"|\" into the system followed by pressing enter twice." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> terminate;
}
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: *"I don't quite understand the phrasing of my C++ Drill"*. Where exactly do you have problems? You've provided two code snippets, but it's not clear what or where your problems are. What is your expected behaviour? What is the behaviour you encounter?

Comment: What is step 6 asking me to do?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you don't understand about it, you need to say what specifically you don't understand about this step.

Comment: @Episha: Leverage formatting. If you quote something, use blockquotes. If you have a rather long text, make sure that the essence is still clear. In this case, I've used a bold face to draw attention, but one could use other techniques.

Comment: Alright, I probably should have looked at the tools given, I'm still somewhat new to posting on sites that have such useful tools.

Comment: Take your favorite [source code editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) (e.g. `emacs`) and replace some of the code in the body between braces `{`...`}` of your loop.

Comment: Read the first two sentences again. You didn't do any of them. (You are not supposed to use a vector; exercise 6 is partly about realising that you don't need to.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you didn't finish step 5. 999 and 1000 are almost equal (difference < 1%).

Ignoring that, your second fragment is a good start at producing the behavior wanted in step 6 but ignores the prescribed method. Yes, a sorted vector has a `.front()` and a `.back()` which are the respective minimum and maximum, but step 6 specifically told you to use two variables instead of a whole vector.

So `double max = std::numeric_limits<double>::max(); double min = -max;` and from there on you should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like:

```
double my_max = numeric_limits<double>::max();
double my_min = -1 * numeric_limits<double>::max();
while (...) {
    ...
    my_min = min(my_min, one);
    my_min = min(my_min, two);
    my_max = max(my_max, one);
    my_max = max(my_max, two);
```